# 403 Error when using htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a htaccess file that redirects all requests to /public/index.php.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access to /testsite"
AuthUserFile /kunden/homepages/28/d446685396/htpasswd
Require user oglover

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . public/index.php [L]
```

It works fine for all requests e.g. www.mywebsite.com/aboutus, www.mywebsite.com/contact, www.mywebsite.com/news etc.... but if i visit www.mywebsite.com/ i get a 403 forbidden error. Everything worked fine until i moved to a new web host and I can't work out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule . public/index.php [L]
```

The regex in this rule, the `.`, means "any single character, anywhere in the string", this causes your problem. When you request `www.mywebsite.com/`, the regex is matched against an empty string (see [What's being matched?](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) in the manual). The regex doesn't matches, so the rule isn't applied, so the server tries to serve the index of root, which is forbidden.

To match everything, change the rule to something like this:

```
RewriteRule .* public/index.php [L]
```

The `.*` means "zero or more characters", which does match the empty string.